# CSS transition from 0px width to 100% width

Tags: css

I have a website where I have set the content to left 100% on normal screen and on click on the button it will show on the screen with left 0%.

I want the transition to be smooth, like the width will increase gradually, not immediately.

I have added     `transition: transform 1s;` on the normal button and on the expand feature, I have used `transform: translate(0px, 0px);` but still that section is opening immediately.

Please check the [page here](https://staging-w5.manufactura-beton.de/shop/bilderahmen/dein-fotodruck-bilderdruck-herzform-beton/) on mobile only.

Here are the buttons [on my question](https://monosnap.com/direct/hBJWfOEM0dFIXkp8p9VdYYY5atE8Y4).

Upon clicking on that, a popup is showing. I want that to come from left slowly. I have used the above CSS but that are not working. You can see the CSS on the page:

```
#tab-description, #tab-additional_information, #tab-video, #tab-fragen, #tab-reviews {
   position: absolute;
   background: #fff;
   right: auto !important;
     left: 100% !important;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
     transition: transform 1s;
}
#tab-description.expand, #tab-additional_information.expand, #tab-video.expand, #tab-fragen.expand, #tab-reviews.expand {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
      height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9;
      left: 0 !important;
    padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To animate a transition with CSS, you need to set `transition` to the property that is changing. You've set `transition: transform 1s;`, which will animate any change to the `transform` property, but the `transform` property *isn't changing* between the two states. The property that *is* changing is `left`, which changes from `100%` to `0`. So that's the property you need to transition:

```
transition: left 1s;
```

Comment: Hello Jacob, Thanks for your reply. I have added the left property previously and it was not working. I have added that now too. Can you please check that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a smooth transition from 0% width to 100% width, you should use the transition property with the width property, not with transform.

With this CSS, when the `.expand` class is added to the element, it will transition from `0%` width to `100%` width over the duration specified in the transition property.

Make sure to remove `!important` from the `left` and width properties in both regular and expanded states to ensure that the transition works as expected

```
#tab-description, #tab-additional_information, #tab-video, #tab-fragen, #tab-reviews {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 1s; /* Apply transition to width property */
}

#tab-description.expand, #tab-additional_information.expand, #tab-video.expand, #tab-fragen.expand, #tab-reviews.expand {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%; /* Adjust width to 100% */
}
```